# Equals values with the last limited row

Tags: mysql, limit

I use a limit query to get a list of the top 5 directors counting also the total of their works e.g.

```
a 137
b 120
c 90
d 76
e 52
```

It really works but what about if with the last row there are also some names with equal works. And it usally happens...

```
f 52
g 52
h 52...
```

the query is:

```
SELECT 
   T_people.person,
   COUNT(ID_films) AS CountOfID_films
FROM
   ((MT_films
   JOIN ST_peoplefilms ON ((MT_films.ID_films = ST_peoplefilms.ID_films)))
   JOIN T_people ON ((T_people.ID_person = ST_peoplefilms.ID_person)))
GROUP BY T_people.person, T_people.man
HAVING (T_people.man = 1)
ORDER BY COUNT(ST_peoplefilms.ID_films) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

thank's a lot

Comment: Well, the question is to get also all the equal values with the last row. thank's

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subquery that gives the top 5 totals. Then use what you have now (you can remove `LIMIT 5` and the ordering) and apply `INNER JOIN` on the subquery with respect to the totals. That will filter away all non-relevant rows.

Comment: Dear Gruber, It already returns top 5 names but how to join the subquery to return also all the equals with the 5th one? Thank's

Comment: @Kostas Konstantinidis: You join _with respect to the top 5 totals_ (the integer values that you have in your subquery), that way you ensure that all entries with a total among the top 5 and nothing else will be returned.